# Best way to share data in a hierarchical class structure

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a hierarchy of four C++ classes: `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`. Each class contains two member variables: a pointer to an object of the class above it in the hierarchy (the *parent*), and a pointer to an object of the class below it (the *child*). For example, class B has a pointer to an object of class `A`, and a pointer to an object of `C`:

```
class B
{
private:
    A* a; // parent
    C* c; // child
}
```

Now, suppose that `A`, the *root* class of the hierarchy, has some member variable `int x`. All classes, from `B` to `D`, also need to access this variable. However, it is neither static nor constant.

There are two ways to go about providing this access, and I'm just wondering **which is the best practice?**

First, I could create a `int GetX()` function for every class. In class `A`, this just returns its value of `x`. In all the other classes, it calls `GetX()` on the parent object. In this way, this call is made throughout the hierarchy until it reaches the root class, and the value is returned along the same path.

Second, I could create another variable `int x` in every class, rather than only in the root class. In the constructor of each child object, I then pass the value of `x` from the parent object. When an object needs to know the value of `x`, it can just read its own value.

The benefit of the first method is that it is more memory efficient, and any changes to `x` can be made just by changing its value in the root class. However, the benefit of the second method is that it is faster to access the value of `x`.

My specific application is creating a decision tree, where each node has a parent and a child, and the root node contains various parameters about the tree which are needed by the nodes.

Comment: Are there inheritance relationship among the classes?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are making a heterogenous linked list (in this case) / tree (general case) of objects that are of different classes. In such a case these objects usually have some sort of inheritance relations.

I have not seen much of these things without some common interface enforcing mechanism like inheritance and polymorphism haha but in this case you can just store a reference to the root in every object or wrap your linked list/tree and provide that class with a `getX()` method. In my opinion wrapping your data structure with another class is a good way to solve this problem. A chain of `getX()` calls might not be very stack-space friendly, when not optimized.

Answer (score 1):

There is a third way, which represents a mixture of your two methods: rather than storing a *copy* of `x`, store a *reference* to it. This would not be as memory-efficient as your first solution, but it would give you convenient access to `x`, which is always up-to-date, because it is a reference:

```
class B {
    A *a;
    C *c;
    int& x;
public:
    B(A *_a, C* _c) : a(_a), C(_c), x(a->x) {}
};
```

Another alternative would be to provide an `A& root()` member function in all classes, which would traverse pointer hierarchy, and return a reference to root object of type `A`. Then you would write

```
int currentX = root().x;
```

in all your classes to access `x` without any copying of information.

I would prefer the first implementation if your hierarchy is deep, and the second implementation if it is shallow (no more than five..ten classes deep).